# Hiding margin with visibillity:collapse

Tags: html

This is my code:

```
<div id="divSpinner" style="margin-top:30px; visibility:collapse;">
</div>
<br />
<div id="divPaging">         
</div>
```

I'm trying to show a spinner, and afterwards show some content in the 'Paging' div (Using Javascript).

The spinner and the 'Paging' div are not visible at the same time, so I've tried to collapse the Spinner visibility, but the 'margin-top' still effects the position of the 'Paging' div.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

you must use **position: absolute;** or **position: relative;** on your **divPaging** css selecting between them related to your code ,if you put link from web page i can say you witch one and how.

Answer (score 0):

I've set 'display: none;' instead of 'visibility:collapse;'